# Google Cloud configurar archivo YAML para un sitio web

Tags: google-cloud-platform

buen día, tengo un sitio web que no contiene mas que arhcivos HTML, JS y plugins como jQuery, Datatables, etc.

Como configuro el archivo YAML para decirle mis archivos de JavaScript están en una ruta, los CSS en otra, tengo una ruta de capas donde hay archivos HTML y una ruta que se llama appends donde están todos los plugins.

El problema es que manda error al momento de querer cargar los archivos JavaScript

Espero me puedan ayudar, les mando muestra de mis rutas.

```
2017-10-24  15:05    <DIR>          appends
2017-10-24  15:05    <DIR>          css
2017-10-24  15:07    <DIR>          img
2017-09-14  08:31             5,759 index.html
2017-01-31  12:57            13,254 index_under.html
2017-11-01  12:33    <DIR>          js
2017-10-27  14:22    <DIR>          layers
```

Mi archivo app.yaml por lo que vi se hace así:

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
handlers:
- url: /favicon.ico
  static_files: img/favicon.ico
  upload: img/favicon.ico
  mime_type: image/x-icon
- url: /css/
  static_dir: static
- url: /img
  static_dir: static
- url: /js
  static_dir: static
- url: /appends
  static_dir: appends
- url: /.*
  script: index.html
```

Answer (score 1):

Sólo me hacia falta esto:

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
handlers:
- url: /favicon.ico
  static_files: img/favicon.ico
  upload: img/favicon.ico
  mime_type: image/x-icon
- url: /css
  static_dir: css/
- url: /img
  static_dir: img/
- url: /js
  static_dir: js/
- url: /appends
  static_dir: appends
- url: /layers
  static_dir: layers/
- url: /.*
  script: index.html
```